# Rails3, and users credentials : which plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I'm starting a new project on Rails3 and my question is about which plugin can i use to manage my users.

I heard about Authlogic  but it seems to don't be compatible with rails3.

So if you have any suggestions, I'll be glad to hear them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to use the Devise plugin. It works very well.

You can then add CanCan plugin written by Ryan Bates

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

For now, install Authlogic as a vendored plugin from Git.

```
$ cd /my/rails/app/
$ rails plugin install git://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic.git
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I gonna try this.